# PRIIPs Stress Scenario calculation category 2

Tags: priips

Can someone explain to me please how to calculate the rolling volatility from  slide 25 in [these slides](https://www.dropbox.com/s/egfx0ktolojfsek/3.PRIIPs%20Workshop%20-%20Risk%20Reward%20Methodology.pdf?dl=0)?

I get the first 21 LN returns like in the example. But then I don't really know what to insert in the formula. I get very different answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the approach described in the PRIIP-RTS annex iv p10-13
https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32017R0653&from=en